# How to code a django site efficiently while accessing database using MySQLdb?

Tags: python, json, django, django-testing

Now i am developing a website in django. But i used MySQLdb to connect with the database instead of django ORM since django ORM doesn't support multiple keys.
I will explain my question with a example, consider i am writing a dictionary to database having type longtext. Hence i have used json.dumps() method to write database.

I am reading those field using another url, hence while coding view function for reading i have used `json.loads()` method to get the dictionary back and here is my question arise. Whether i need to handle the exception when database field hold a non json string. If database field hold a non json string `json.loads()` will produce ValueError.

Whether i need to catch those type of error since chance of having database with non json string is very little.

Answer (score 0):

It's down to preference but personally I try to catch all potential errors, you never know what other issues they might expose.

And ofcourse, there's the "Zen of Python": "Errors should never pass silently.
Unless explicitly silenced"

Comment: What if the error is not catched? Is there any potential issue?

Comment: Also there is no chance to alter the database unless anyone tries to do with sql shell. Is there any chance to alter the table values by any means?

Comment: An uncaught error will result in a 500 error for the web request. There can also be side effects like inconsistent database states. But that depends on your code.

Comment: @mcvishnu Not in general. There are even good causes to raises exception up the the request handler, so it can respond with certain HTTP codes. But basically an exception is often a situation you did not think of while developing and that is the actual danger of it. Silencing an exception or even all exception unconditionally is even more dangerous since you will not see that there is a problem.

Comment: @mcvishnu I should also add that in DEBUG mode Django responds to an exception with a debug page containing all kind of information. So having DEBUG mode on in production is dangerous and will "help hackers".

Comment: @KlausD. What will be your opinion? Whether to handle those error or not?

Comment: Why i am asking this that, database only change when we change it through sql shell. No outsiders or hackers can change the database. Am i right? So i am sure that, there will be no change in database and hence no Exceptions will raise.

Comment: SO is not an opinion board. So I try stick with facts and experiences. It will be your part to draw conclusions from it. Hiw tamper proof your DB is depends more on setup, permissions and the proper use of the ORM than on exception handling.